# Characterisation of a maximal filter

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, filters

Let $F \subset B$ be a proper filter. Prove that $F$ is maximal if and only if for all $p \in B$ with the property that $p \wedge q \ne 0$, for all $q \in F$, the $p$ is also in $F$. I've used a characterisation of maximal filter which states that a filter $F$ is maximal if and only if either $p$ or $p^c$ are in $F$, for all $p \in B$

What I've proved is the following:

- Let F be a maximal filter. Suppose there is a $p \in B$, such that $p \wedge q \ne 0$, for all $q \in B$, but $p \notin F$. Because the $F$ is maximal and $p \notin F$ it must be $p^c \in F$. But now $0 = p \wedge p^c \ne 0$, because $p^c \in F$. Hence, first implication is correct.
- Let F be a proper filter with the property that for all $p \in B$ for which $p \wedge q \ne 0$, for all $q \in F$ the $p$ is also in $F$. Let $p \in B$ be an arbitrary element. The $p$ either has the stated property or doesn't. If it does, the $p \in F$, hence $F$ is maximal. On the other hand, if there is a $q \in F$ such that $p \wedge q = 0$, does that imply that $q = p^c$? In that case $F$ would still be maximal, but I can't figure bit out.

Am I doing it right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do believe that "proper filter" is the more usual term instead of "genuine filter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second bullet point, what you really want to prove is that, for each $p \in B$, either $p \in F$ or $p' \in F$.

Now, if $p \notin F$, then, by the property that defines $F$, we have that $p \wedge q = 0$, for some $q \in F$, whence $q \leq p'$, yielding $p' \in F$.

---

### Update.

About the question in your comment, from $p \wedge q = 0$ it follows that $q \leq p'$, using the well known Boolean laws:
$$x \wedge y' = 0 \;\Longleftrightarrow\; x \leq y$$
and $x''=x$.

I'll prove directly the required implication.
If $p \wedge q = 0$, then
\begin{align}
q \wedge p'
&= (q \wedge p') \vee 0\\
&= (q \wedge p') \vee (q \wedge p)\\
&= q \wedge (p' \vee p)\\
&= q \wedge 1 = q,
\end{align}
whence $q \leq p'$.

Comment: But why is $q \le p^c$? How could I prove that?

Comment: @NemanjaBeric I updated the answer.